# Prestashop function query to the template

Tags: sql, variables, prestashop, smarty

I am in prestashop 1.6 and in classes/Cart.php i've tested and i can communicate with the template file.
In the query that i've made to return the expect result works on phpmyadmin, and works in cart.php to tpl file call, but only when i write the id number of the customer, and i want to work with the variable id customer (something with THIS or like prestashop way of work - (int)$id_customer - ).
Any help please!!!!!

//code for cart.php

```
public static function payLater($id_customer)
{
    $sql =  "SELECT ps_customer.pay_later
            FROM ps_customer
            LEFT JOIN ps_cart ON ps_customer.id_customer = ps_cart.id_customer
            ORDER BY ps_cart.id_cart DESC LIMIT 1
            WHERE ps_cart.id_customer =".(int)$id_customer;
    //if i change (int)$id_customer for a real id number like 43 it shows correct info
    $result = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);
    return $result;
}
```

//code for template file

```
{Cart::payLater(Tools::getvalue('pay_later'))}
```

Answer (score 0):

{Cart::payLater($customer.id)} in tpl file. I have edited in your function also. please check below for empty customer id.

```
public static function payLater($id_customer)
{
   if((int)$id_customer == 0){ return; } // check if customer id is blank
    $sql =  "SELECT ps_customer.pay_later
            FROM ps_customer
            LEFT JOIN ps_cart ON ps_customer.id_customer = ps_cart.id_customer
            ORDER BY ps_cart.id_cart DESC LIMIT 1
            WHERE ps_cart.id_customer =".(int)$id_customer;
    //if i change (int)$id_customer for a real id number like 43 it shows correct info
    $result = Db::getInstance()->getValue($sql);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Did you print $customer.id in your tpl file? What you get?